# Pythagoras' theorem proof when given that the shortest distance between two points is a straight line

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, calculus-of-variations

I have found myself in a corner with this proof after working with it for the whole day and would appreciate input. As a reverse to proving that the shortest distance between two points via Pythagoras' theorem, I am attempting to prove the Pythagoras' theorem in an Euclidian space, given that it is known that the shortest distance between two points is a straight line. Is this even possible, or is it possibly even trivial? What am I missing here?

I have tried several different approaches, but none have yet yielded anything. I am thinking the most logical way to go about proving this would be to begin with that the hypotenuse is less or equal than to the sum of the legs of a straight triangle.

Comment: What are you axioms and definitions?  If you can't use any of the standard proofs one assumes you are working with a different set of axioms.  But we have no idea which one?  How do you prove the shortest distance is a straight line.  Is that not an axiom?  We can't help you if we don't know what universe you live in.

Comment: I have proven via calculus of variations that the shortest distance between two points is a straight line (like here http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node86.html) in a two dimensional real space. The difficulty is that I'm supposed to only use this result of calculus of variations to prove Pythagoras.

Comment: But the first formula in that page makes use of Pythagoras' theorem (see square root inside integral).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. It is assumed that Euclidean distance theorems hold without assuming Pythagoras, and the main problem is to derive Pythagoras from the result, not necessarily minding if it's a "circular"? proof.